# Java - movePlayerWithMouse not changing boolean with !movePlayerWithMouse and TAB

Tags: java

My method some reason doesnt work I want it so when I click tab it grabs the mouse and moves the player but when clicked again I want it to release the mouse and stop the players rotation I tried putting a print statement into the movePlayerWithMouse method but it just returns true the only thing that does change is the mouse each time I click tab it releases and grabs any help?
Heres the method I use:

```
  boolean movePlayerWithMouse = false;

  while(Keyboard.next()) {   
      if(!Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
          if(Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_TAB) {
              movePlayerWithMouse = !movePlayerWithMouse;
             Mouse.setGrabbed(!Mouse.isGrabbed());
          }
      }
  }
  if(movePlayerWithMouse = !movePlayerWithMouse) {
     rotY -= Mouse.getDX() / SENSITIVITY;
  }
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question quite well, but just looking at your code, I found a potential issue: do you really want to invert the boolean value with this instruction "if (movePlayerWithMouse = !movePlayerWithMouse)"? I hope you know what you're doing :-)

Comment: Yh I do as I want it so moveplayerwithmouse is true and mouse is grabed and when false it should stop

Comment: I think atleast what can i do?